# Crystal Reports database field doesn't update automatically

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, crystal-reports

On my CR9 report, I have a database field called `invoiceNumber`, which stores an integer. In the database (SQL Server 2008), this value is updated every time an invoice is printed or emailed to a customer.

The value updates fine in the database, however on the report it only updates if I open the report in CR and verify the database. This is not what the user should have to do, for obvious reasons, so is there anything that might be causing the issue? I don't understand why the value on the report doesn't update automatically with the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Crystal Reports, open the .rpt that is cause the issue and go to `File` and uncheck `Save data with report`, as this means you'll need to manually refresh it to update, whereas unchecking it means it will do it by itself, as the data isn't saved to the report.